# Margin problems in CSS IE vs Firefox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, xhtml

I'm trying to make a banner in HTML/CSS. However, I'm having trouble with the margins in one of my div's. It works perfectly in Firefox, but not in IE.

```
#lowerText{
       float: left;
       margin-top: 50px; 
       margin-left: -185px;
       color: rgb(255, 199, 142); 
       font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive; 
       font-size: 15px; 
       text-transform: uppercase;
       display:inline;
}

#upperText{
      float: left;
      margin-left: 20px; 
      margin-top: -10px; 
      color: rgb(255, 199, 142); 
      font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive; 
      font-size: 30px; 
      text-transform: uppercase;
      display:inline;
}
```

It's an `h3` tag in `#lowerText` which says "-Foo foo foo bar". In IE it only shows: "oo bar". The text in this div HAS to be right underneath `#upperText` at a specfic position. But the `margin-left: 185px` in `#lowerText` doesn't show in IE, but it shows in Firefox.

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Can you show what you have so far? http://jsbin.com/

Comment: what do you mean, what I have so far?

Comment: I mean, can you make a JS Bin demo containing your HTML/CSS that reproduces your problem. Making a demo enables us to answer your question more easily.

Comment: I think this should work: http://jsbin.com/ubolog/edit#javascript,html If you open this in Firefox, it is how it should be. But if you try IE9, you'll see that the text doesn't come off right.

Comment: That's strange. I opened the link I posted in my previous comment in IE, clicked the Render button. And the banner is fine, wth.

Answer (score 0):

In your comment, you state your jsfiddle works in IE. jsfiddle auto inserts a doctype which I now assume you do not have in your original page. If so, IE is in quirks mode without the doctype and the cause of your problem (other than IE being the worst browser on the planet).

EDIT: Didn't look first. jsfiddle shows a doctype. Did you put that there?